# Aggregate data in a column based on another column from a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have some data like below:

```
A B
1 a
2 b
1 c
3 d
2 e
```

I want to transform this into something like: (A and B are column headers)

```
A B
1 c(a,c)
2 c(b,e)
3 d
```

I tried using aggregate but it is not turning out as expected.

Comment: Your desired output is not clear. You want a list column or just concatenate the values?

Comment: A list column would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `tapply()` with a function call to `c()`, like so:

```
A <- rep(letters[1:2], 5)
B <- rep(1:2, each = 5)

tapply(A, B, c)
```

You'll get a list as output:

```
$`1`
[1] "a" "b" "a" "b" "a"

$`2`
[1] "b" "a" "b" "a" "b"
```